# Update table row based on 3 OR conditions

Tags: sql-server

I have a table  that contains three user ID columns and an Active column

### Table1

userID1
userID2
userID3
Active

I want to set each row to be inactive (Active = 0) where given two UserIDs exist in the same row. Whats the fastest and most logical way to achieve this?

Thanks!

---

EDIT: Sorry I should have been a bit more clear in my question. UserID1,2 and 3 will ALWAYS contain user ID's. They will never be null. I will be passing through these IDs as parameters in a stored proc and so I need to set Active = 0 where two user IDs out of UserID1, UserID2 or UserID3 both exist in the same row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE  Table1
SET     Active = 0
WHERE   @userID1 IN (userID1,userID2,userID3)
AND     @userID2 IN (userID1,userID2,userID3);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE Table1
SET Active  = 0
WHERE 1 = 
    CASE
        WHEN UserID1 IS NOT NULL AND UserID2 IS NOT NULL THEN 1
        WHEN UserID1 IS NOT NULL AND UserID3 IS NOT NULL THEN 1
        WHEN UserID2 IS NOT NULL AND UserID3 IS NOT NULL THEN 1
    END
```

The case can help with efficiency if you know a common case. It will keep the other cases and or's from having to be executed.

Comment: good, this wont change the value of the other users. I assumed they had to be updated to 1

Comment: Actually, I guess I overthought it with the OR on my end. Updating my answer to not need the OR in the WHEN

Comment: I actually dont think you need all those checks. take a look at mine. I up-voted yours because it doesnt touche the, lets call, OK users

Comment: Yah, I updated it. I really try to catch myself from overthinking solutions, but sometimes do it anyway. Thanks for the catch

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that when the user doesnt exist, it is null.
Also, it will update all the Active users to 1

```
update Table1 
set Active = case
            when (userID1 is not null and userID2 is not null) then 0 
            when (userID1 is not null and userID3 is not null) then 0 
            when (userID2 is not null and userID3 is not null) then 0
            else 1 
        end
```